# PL-SQL query to find the most recent record the "Operation_date" of which is lower than a specified date

Tags: oracle, query-performance, oracle-11g-r2, query, plsql

I have a table with below structure:

```
create table DOC_AMOUNT_DETAIL
(
  col_id         NUMBER,
  amount         NUMBER,
  operation_date DATE      
)
```

some example data for this table is :

```
col_id    |  amount   |  operation_date 
---------------------------------------
  1       |  5000     |  11/1/2020  
  2       |  1000     |  11/1/2020 
  3       |  3000     |  11/1/2020     
  1       |  1000     |  11/14/2020
  2       |   500     |  11/14/2020
```

If the `amount` column of each `col_id` changes , a `new record` will be inserted in the table with a new `operation_date` which is exactly the date of the change. What I need from the table is the amount for each col_id which has the `max(operation_date)<= (a specific date for example 11/15/2020)` by this I mean I need the last update of the record the `operation_date of which is lower than the date I'm querying the table`. So my desired result is this :

```
    col_id    |  amount   
    --------------------
      1       |  1000      
      2       |  500    
      3       |  3000
```

What I've written so far is this and it gives me the correct output:

```
select d.col_id, 
       d.amount
  from doc_amount_detail d
 inner join (select t.col_id, 
             max(t.operation_date) operation_date
               from doc_amount_detail t
              where t.operation_date <= to_date('11/15/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
              group by t.col_id
             ) d2
    on d.col_id = d2.col_id
   and d.operation_date = d2.operation_date
```

and I want to know whether there are better ways of writing this query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `LAST_VALUE` would be one way.

Comment: @MichaelKutz This one gives me the wrong result : select t.col_id,
       last_value(t.amount) over(partition by t.col_id order by t.operation_date) amount
from doc_amount_detail t
where t.operation_date <= to_date('11/15/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

Comment: I believe this falls under "Top N" query category.  I'm sure there is a Wiki/FAQ on here for Oracle. I was requested to add `MATCH RECOGNIZE` to potential solutions but lost the link. (Haven't found it yet)

Comment: @MichaelKutz , I used first_value function instead of last_value which I think is a bit tricky and at the same time a bit scary !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution. Instead of `Last_value()` function , I used `First_value()` and `order by t.operation_date desc`:

```
select distinct 
       t.col_id,
       first_value(t.amount) over(partition by t.col_id order by t.operation_date desc ) amount
from doc_amount_detail t
where t.operation_date <= to_date('11/15/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 1):

[Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm)

```
select
  col_id, amount
from
 (
   select
     d.col_id, d.amount,
     rank() over (partition by d.col_id order by d.operation_date desc) as rk
   from doc_amount_detail d
   where.d.operation_date <= to_date('11/15/2020', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
 )
where rk = 1;
```